# Secure Galaxy Star GT-S5282 using simcard change alert

Tags: settings, security, samsung-galaxy-star

How can I secure my Samsung Galaxy Star GT-S5282 using the simcard change alert option. In other words, when a simcard is inserted in my phone a notification SMS is sent to other phones.